# How to spy on typescript class using jasmine?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I have a class that is calling backend to get data , so in below code i tried to write unit test for the class in order to mock it using spyOn so i can get the desire result, it is failing to import the class , Any idea how spyOn class methods using jasmine ?

Basically trying to spyOn on `core` method and underlying calls.

DrugPriceApi.ts

```
export class DrugPriceApi extends Types.ModuleBase < DrugPriceParam, DrugPriceResultSet[] > {

    private _memberId: string = "";
    private _dependencies: any;
    private errorMessage: string = "There was an issue while retrieving drug price. Please try again.";

    before(args: DrugPriceParam): Promise < DrugPriceParam > {
        args.daysSupply = args.daysSupply ? args.daysSupply : args.appName === "VOYA" ? "90" : "BLNK";
        return Promise.resolve(args);
    }

    core(args: DrugPriceParam, requestMethod: Interface.Core.RequestMethod, _dependencies: any): Promise < any > {
        this._dependencies = _dependencies;

        return new Promise < any > ((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
               this.getDrug(function(resolve){ resolve( //response here);});
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

DrugPriceApi.spec.ts

```
import { Interface } from "dist/karma/core-sdk-lib/src/ts/interface/index";
import { } from 'jasmine';
import { Index } from "../../../../../index";
import { setup } from "dist/karma/core-sdk-lib/src/ts/helper/TestSetup.helper";
import { CApiSettings, CLogger } from "@cvsdigital_specialty/common-utils";
import { DrugPriceParam } from "./DrugPriceApi.interface";
import {DrugPriceApi} from "./DrugPriceApi.node";
    describe("Module", () => {
        let _sdkInstance: any;
        let param = {
            tokenId: '123',
            appName: 'CMK_TEST',
            refId: '123'
        } as DrugPriceParam;

        let memberInfo: any = {};
        memberInfo.dateOfBirth = "11/11/11";
        memberInfo.externalID = "6172";
        memberInfo.internalID = "12";
        memberInfo.clientId = "22322";
        memberInfo.planId = "902H93";
        memberInfo.eligibility = {
            "benefitPlanList": {
                "benefitPlan": [
                    {
                        "active": true,
                        "deliverySystem": 2,
                    },
                    {
                        "active": true,
                        "deliverySystem": 3,
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        param.memberInfo = memberInfo;
        beforeEach(() => {
            spyOn(DrugPriceApi, 'core' as any).and.returnValue(1); // 'as any' prevents compiler warning
          });

          it('verifies that core was called', () => {
            const module = DrugPriceApi.core(param);
          });

    });
```

Comment: I don't see you creating an instance of `DrugPriceApi` in your tests, however the methods in your class are instance methods rather than static methods. You will need to create a reference via `drugPriceApi = new DrugPriceApi()` and use that in the places where you are trying to use `DrugPriceApi` (i.e. `spyOn(DrugPriceApi, 'core')` and `DrugPriceApi.core(param)`)

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel ok thanks for the help, how do we call inherited methods that are private to class , there are methods in core that i wanted to test , Any idea ? i updated my question so in core we are calling getDrug how can i test that call ?

Comment: You don't mock out private methods in tests (esp. as there isn't a way if it is truly private). You mock out the external interface. If you need to mock out internals in a class that gives you an indication that you probably need to break out some logic into another class with public methods that you can mock out.

Comment: understood but how to cover that in coverage report it shows still untested code

Comment: You will have to provide more details about the code to try to help you out with testing the class. You don't mock out methods of the class you are trying to test. You mock out dependencies that it uses. If you can show the relevant code in the class, we can try to help you determine how to test what you are doing.